# Store IP Addreess in single column

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code which insert a single value of IP Address when user login.
If the user tries to login from a different IP then user will get an email to confirm. After the user clicks on the link sent in the email, the IP address is updated. Instead of updating the IP adddress, I want to store all IPs when whenever the user confirms its identity so that if the user can be able to login same IP that we have stored in our array.

Basically I want to store IP address as an array.

```
<?php

       include 'header.php';
   include('config.php');
         $eemail=$_GET['email'];

        if(isset($_POST['scode']))
        {
     $unncode=$_POST['uncode'];

      $sql1="SELECT * FROM nennetwork WHERE code ='$unncode'";
        $res=mysql_query($sql1);

    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);

     $ccode = $rows['code'] ;

      if($unncode==$ccode)
     $eemail=$_GET['email'];
       $ips = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   if(mysql_query("update nennetwork set useripp= '".$ips ."' WHERE email ='$eemail'"))
        {
       $mmmsg= "You can <a href='".'index.php'."' class='ac'>Login</a> if the code matches the code that we have sent you.";


      }


      else{

     $mmmsg="Please submit the numeric code that we sent to your email.";

     }}

        ?>
```

Comment: Can you include some error output?

Comment: there s no error, code is working fine it update the value but doesnt insert a new value

Comment: "If the user tries to login from a different Ip then user will get an email to confirm." please don't mine can change several times a day

Comment: I have given the update query but i want to insert a new value keeping previous as well.

Comment: yes but i want to store all values

Comment: You can create a new table with user id and ip address. Each time user visits your sites you can insert a ip address if not exists. Their will be multiple entries with the same user id and you can use the same table to compare ip's

Comment: off topic but your website can be hacked within like 3 seconds if you don't use `prepared statements` and `mysqli` instead of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Ok, besides a massive case for SQL injection (READ UP ON php-pdo on php.net, great simple to use examples).

The troublesome query for you which does not insert:

if(mysql_query("update nennetwork set useripp= '".$ips ."' WHERE email ='$eemail'"))

Could be replaced by:

```
INSERT INTO nennetwork (useripp, email) VALUES (?,?) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE useripp=?;
```

For this to work you will need 1 index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_nennetwork_nn_1 ON nennetwork(email);
```

This will cause the duplicate key to trigger the update or the insert depending on the data involved.

(Read php-pdo on how to get the ?,? and ? be replaced by bind variables and some safer code).

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the data correctly so that you don't need to store an array in your table.

In this case you should have a separate table with IP addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE your_user_ip (
 id int primary key auto_increment,
 userid int not null
 ip varchar(5) not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.

> There are some errors on your code all fixed.

```
include 'header.php';
include('config.php');
$eemail=$_REQUEST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['scode']))
{
    $unncode=$_POST['uncode'];

    $sql1="SELECT * FROM nennetwork WHERE code ='$unncode'";
    $res= mysql_query($sql1);

    $count = count($res);
    if(empty($count))
    {
        echo 'Query is empty ';
    }
    else
    {
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        $ccode = $rows['code'] ;

        if($unncode == $ccode)
        {
            $eemail = $_REQUEST['email'];
            $ips = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            if(mysql_query("update nennetwork set useripp= '$ips ' WHERE email ='$eemail'"))
            {
                $mmmsg= "You can <a href='".'index.php'."' class='ac'>Login</a> if the code matches the code that we have sent you.";
            }
            else
            {

                $mmmsg="Please submit the numeric code that we sent to your email.";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "unncode not matced with ccode ";
        }

    }

}
```

and SQL table should be

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
 id int primary key auto_increment,
 useripp int not null,
 email varchar(30) not null,
 code  varchar(30) not null);
```